# Combination of names on passport differs from marriage certificate

Tags: visas, uk, weddings, nigeria

My husband bears 3 names. He used the names interchangeable on his passport and marriage certificate. on his Nigeria passport is Udo ikechi obinna. While on our marriage certificate his used his baptismal name which is Udo Benjamin ikechi. We are planning to apply for UK Visa as married couple so we will be presenting our marriage certificate. Will the difference in name post a problem for us or is there any kind of document or action to take to prove that he bears the 3 names.

Comment: If I’ve understood your question correctly, your husband’s birth certificate matches his marriage certificate, but neither match his passport? IMHO it is highly likely that the inconsistency in the names will be problematic. Can he get a new passport issued in his baptismal name? You’d probably be wise to consult an Immigration lawyer with expertise in UK visa applications https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/

Comment: No I mean my husband birth certificate correspond with his passport but does not correspond with our marriage certificate

Comment: The discrepancy will 100% be a problem. You need advice from a qualified immigration adviser with experience in UK immigration IMHO You could try eg https://home.oisc.gov.uk/register_of_regulated_immigration_advisers/register.aspx